# uwp CalendarDatePicker not binding to Date Property

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm triying to bind a `DateTime` from the ViewModel to a `calendarDatePicker`, but it doesn't work. i've tried in a `textbox` and works.

This part works:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyDate}" ></TextBox>
```

And this doesn't:

```
<CalendarDatePicker Date="{Binding MyDate}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was previously answered [here on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/0e1fc1dd-3ff0-4a27-ad99-a82a0f6577e9/uwpxamlcalendardatepicker-not-binding-to-date-property?forum=wpdevelop).

Per the article, you could use a `Converter` to convert the binding to a `DateTimeOffset`. The converter may look something like the following, which comes from [this post](http://bretstateham.com/binding-to-the-new-xaml-datepicker-and-timepicker-controls-to-the-same-datetime-value/) (referenced by the MSDN answer):

```
public class DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)value;
            return new DateTimeOffset(date);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTimeOffset.MinValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            return dto.DateTime;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, Date ="{Binding MyDate, Mode=TwoWay ,Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffset}}"